# Download SEAndroid for AOSP base on repo Issue

Tags: git, android-source, repo

I refer [this](http://seandroid.bitbucket.org/Usingthemasterbranch.html#4_1)
Download SEAndroid but the following error occurs.

```
Retrying clone after deleting None
error: Cannot fetch system-vold (GitError: --force-sync not enabled; cannot overwrite a local work tree)
Fetching project platform/external/libssh2
Exception in thread Thread-37: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/lee/seandroid-5.1.1/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 254, in _FetchProjectList
success = self._FetchHelper(opt, project, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lee/seandroid-5.1.1/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 297, in _FetchHelper
optimized_fetch=opt.optimized_fetch)
  File "/home/lee/seandroid-5.1.1/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1144, in Sync_NetworkHalf
self._InitGitDir(force_sync=force_sync)
  File "/home/lee/seandroid-5.1.1/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2198, in _InitGitDir
raise e
GitError: --force-sync not enabled; cannot overwrite a local work tree

Fetching projects:   7% (35/487)  
error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your repo's version, the latest version is 1.21, you can try the older version.

Answer (score 2):

From now on, to rewrite a newer version of repo, over the older version, use:

```
repo sync --force-sync
```